# case inner select query checking data

Tags: oracle

I am doing insert into a table, while inserting I am checking if a table have data or no. the query is wrong I need someone to fix it please.

```
insert into tab1 values (code , message)
values (1 , (select count(1)
             from user_errors
             where name ='PROC1' case If count(1) = 1 message ='error'
                                      else message='clean')
```

I want to write an inner select to check if the procedure `PROC1` have error , if the procedure exists in user errors then I should add in column message error

**Edit:** This is the code:

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (message, user)
 VALUES( 
    (select case when count(1) = 1 then 'error' else 'clean' end 
     from user_errors
     where name = 'P_EMPLOYEE' and sequence = 1),
    (SELECT TEXT
     FROM USER_ERRORS
     WHERE NAME = 'P_EMPLOYEE' AND SEQUENCE = 1),
    (SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') || '-' ||
     SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER') || '-' ||
     SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'TERMINAL')
     FROM DUAL)
 )
```

Comment: Are you sure you have only one record in your `user_errors` table?

Comment: I will add condition sequence ... select count(1) from user_errors where name='PROC1' and sequence = 1 @zaratustra

Comment: You can't have a column with the `user` name, this is a predefined word in Oracle Database, change it to `usr` at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrite your query:

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (code, message, usr)
values(
  case
    when nvl((select count(*) from user_errors where name = 'P_EMPLOYEE' and sequence = 1 group by text), 0) = 0  then 'clean'
    else 'error'
  end
, (select text txt from user_errors where name = 'P_EMPLOYEE' and sequence = 1 group by text)
, SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') || '-' || SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER') || '-' || SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'TERMINAL')
)
```

If the user_errors view has records (doesn't matter how many) about `P_EMPLOYEE` then you have to mark it as `error` else you mark it as `clean`.

But if I had this task I wouldn't store this data in any table, I would get this info directly from the `user_errors` view.

Comment: what value? You was going to insert 1 as the value for the code column.

Comment: I have a secnerio that needs to get the value for user error , but with above query I am not able into to insert the value code

Comment: update your post and show us either the table or view or sequence or whatever that gets you values for the `code` column.

Comment: @Moudiz you have in the `insert` section only two fields but in the `values` there are three select, you have to decide what you really need